# How to focus RecyclerView top position inside NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

Not able t focus the `recyclerview` top position inside `NestedScrollView`.

I have the following structure of the xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:id="@+id/nested_scroll"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_above="@+id/cv_comment_post">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/card_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_2dp">
       <!-- Some Views of -->
       </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/card_view" />
        </RelativeLayout>
     </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

When i am notify the recyclerview adapter then it's not focus to the top of `RecyclerView` using below code

```
   mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
```